# jQuery page sometimes load, sometimes not

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

As  you can see, the javascript makes one validation. It checks if the input have or not text.

What happens is that if I Refresh the page, insert something in the input and submit the form, **works great**. But, if I Refresh the page, did not insert anything in the search, and submit the form, it happens nothing (**and thats ok..**), but right after that, if I insert something in the input search it does not validate. To work again, I have to refresh again the page, how can I avoid this?

```
  <form id="page-main-add-form" style="display:inline;" method="POST">
        <table style="margin-left:0px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
                <td><input id="page-main-add-post-btn" value="new" type="submit" data-role="none"/></td>
                <td style="width: 100%"><input id="page-main-add-post-box" size="40" type="text" data-role="none"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>

$('#page-main-add-form').submit(function() {
    var value = $('#page-main-add-post-box').val();
    if(value != ''){
        $('#page-add-value-box').val(value);
        $.mobile.changePage($("#page-add"), "slideUp");
        return false;
    }
});
```

**Edit:** Solved with `location.reload();` after the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Try this little change, [**Working Demo**](http://jsbin.com/ipUKIFO/2/edit)

```
$('#page-main-add-form').submit(function(e) {
 var value = $('#page-main-add-post-box').val();
 if(value === ""){
    e.preventDefault();  //just cancelling the default action of your form
    $('#page-add-value-box').val(value);
    $.mobile.changePage($("#page-add"), "slideUp");
 }
});
```

What i have done is cancelled the only default action of submit handler and put it just after it validates the value of input text box. I could have put `return false` here but that would stop the code from propagating further. Please left a comment if you still getting any issue. hope that helps.

Comment: That doesn't worked. It had the same error I was getting in the beginning. Look at my answer, and thanks.

Comment: what is `$.mobile.changePage($("#page-add"), "slideUp")` doing?